# How to implement environments between Google Tag Manager and Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

The goal is to have the Dev and Live env from Google Tag Manager map to Dev and Live environments on Universal Analytics.

About UA, from what I know, it doesn't have environments, so I would just create two properties, under Admin, each representing an environment.

Now, I've got to a point where I create the environments in Google Tag Manger. How do I proceed from here in order to link them to the appropriate UA properties?

[image]

If I'm taking a wrong approach, please steer me away.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I tried to follow the article posted in your answer but it didn’t work for me.

Comment: @PeterW it's been a while, but yeah, i posted it cz it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer in [this article](https://www.napkyn.com/2017/07/12/ga-gtm-environments/).

In short:

1. Create your two (Dev, Prod) UA properties and note their Tracking Codes
2. In the GTM console, save those Tracking Codes as constants
3. Enable `Environment Name` Built-In Variable
4. Create new Lookup Table Variable that outputs Tracking Code based on Environment Name
5. Provide the Lookup Table Variable to the Universal Analytics tag

Comment: It wasn’t working for me but I figured out my problem. I was trying to use Google Analytics Settings Variables instead of a Constant Variable. Google Analytics Settings Variables don’t work in Lookup Variable at this time.